# promediar latitudes y longitudes cercanas + python

Tags: python, array

Buenas. Tengo un vector con 17000 latitudes y otro con 17000 longitudes. O si lo mismo, en un vector de partes ordenados [lat, lon]

La idea seria q todos los puntos dentro de un area se unifiquen. Es decir, supongamos q dividimos el mapa en celdas de 0.25 * 0.25 . entonces, promediar todos los puntos que se encuentren en ese cuadrado.

las lats van de -90 a 90 y longs de 0 a 360.

```
latmenor = -90.
lonmenor = 0
steplat = 0.25

auxlat = []
auxfinlat = []

print "Lats size!", lats.size

auxlat = []
VectorVectoresLat = []
h = 0

while h != 180:
    if auxlat != []:
        VectorVectoresLat.append(np.average(auxlat))
    auxlat=[]
    for i in range(lats.size):
        if latmenor < lats[i] < (latmenor+steplat):
             auxlat.append(lats[i])
    h=h+steplat
    latmenor = latmenor + steplat

print VectorVectoresLat
print "longitud de aux2", len(VectorVectoresLat)
```

pude hacerlo con las latitudes, pero no logro q funcione teniendo en cuenta las longitudes.. alguna ayuda? gracias!!

lats = vector con latitudes

lon = vector con longitudes.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, puedes ejemplemficar la salida que deseas obtener

Comment: Creo que lo que explicas en la pregunta y el código que añades no indican lo mismo o no te estoy entendiendo bien. Viendo que usas `np.average` entiendo que tienes numpy disponible. ¿Por qué no haces uso de numpy para todo? Te doy alguna pista: échale un ojo a `np.digitize` a ver si te da alguna idea.

Comment: Yo lo que no entiendo es para qué promediar latitudes y longitudes. Tiene pintas de ser más un problema en el que se quiere aplicar [*k-means*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means).

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que si en una celda de 0.25x0.25 no hay ningún elemento, ¿qué se supone que tiene que salir? Algo falta en el enunciado.

Comment: Bien, gracias. Ahora mismo busco sobre 'digitize'.  Respecto a la consiga, la idea final sera implementar una especie de superObbing. Si en la celda no hay nada, pues la ignoro, no tomo nada... el punto es, q en un espacio de 0,25x0,25 tengo X cantidad de valores. A futuro, lo q pienso a hacer es promediar tambien el atrubuto asociado a esas coordenadas.

Comment: De modo que en cada celda quede, ya sea vacía o con un solo valor. Me explico?

Answer (score 1):

Algo bueno de python es que maneja bastante bien las tuplas. En lugar de tener dos listas separadas, con latitudes y longitudes, es mejor tener una sóla lista de tuplas:

```
coords = zip(lats, lon)
```

Pero antes vamos a hacerlo mejor. La característica que identifica a cada coordenada es la celda a la que pertenece. El mejor modo de manipular celdas es con un diccionario:

```
cells = {(i,j):None for i in range(-90,  90, 0.25)
                    for j in range(  0, 360, 0.25) }
```

`cells` será nuestro resultado final. El valor `None` será el valor que tengan las celdas que no tengan ni un sólo punto.

Habría que tener cuidado con las condiciones de borde y empezar, por ejemplo, en la latitud `-90+0.25`, pero como no se especifica nada en el problema lo dejamos tal cual.

Lo de calcular la media de las coordenadas de los puntos de una celda no tiene mucho sentido. Supongo que cada punto tiene un atributo que es realmente lo que interesa promediar, pero vamos a ajustarnos al enunciado:

Supongamos que queremos promediar las coordenadas. El promedio de una lista de coordenadas lo obtenemos con la  siguiente función `average`:

```
def average(coords):
    n = len(coords)
    return (sum(x for (x,_) in coords)/n,
            sum(y for (_,y) in coords)/n)
```

Por otro lado, para saber la celda a la que pertenece una coordenada:

```
from math import floor

def find_cell(coord):
    return (floor(coord[0]*4)/4, floor(coord[1]*4)/4))
```

Esta función la podemos usar como *clave* para agrupar los puntos que pertenecen a la misma celda con la función `itertools.groupby`. Esta función requiere que la lista esté previamente ordenada.

Combinándolo todo quedaría:

```
from itertools import groupby

cells = {(i,j):None for i in range(-90,  90, 0.25)
                    for j in range(  0, 360, 0.25) }

coords = sorted(zip(lats,lon), key=find_cell)

cells.update(
    (k,average(lst)) for (k,lst) in groupby(coords, key=find_cell)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ante todo, disculpen la demora pero estuve un tanto enfermo.
@ChemaCortes, **muchas gracias** por el aporte. Justamente, había leído sobre las tuplas y estaba probando por este camino, también resolví el problema planteado y quería compartirles como lo hice. Adjunto el código, y cualquier comentario q hagan al respecto es muy bienvenido! Si se puede mejorar, o si hay formas de optimizarlo? De hecho, tengo entendido q la sentencia FOR no es el fuerte de python :>( y **el programa resulta muy lento cuando son muchos los datos.** 
Una vez mas, gracias por el apoyo. Siendo nuevo en todo esto, es bueno saber que se cuenta cn una comunidad como esta.

```
    lats = read_var(nc_file, 'lat')
    lon = read_var(nc_file, 'lon')
    print len(lats)
    #lats = lats[0:200] #reduir los vectores para probar funconamiento mas rapido.
    #lon = lon[0:200]

    coordenadas = []
    aux = []

    coordenadas = zip(lats,lon)
    #for i in range(lats.size):
            #aux.append(lats[i])
            #aux.append(lon[i])
            #coordenadas.append(aux)
            #aux = []

    #print coordenadas

    #lats -90 a 90
    #long 0-360

    factor = (int(max(lats)) - int(min(lats))-1) #sumo al max y resto  al min para tomar tmb los datos marginales
    unaLat = int(min(lats)-1)
    todasLat = []
    step = 0.25
    rang = int((1/step)*factor)+1
    for i in range(rang): #multiplicar en funcion de cual es el step
        todasLat.append(unaLat)
        unaLat = unaLat + step
    #print todasLat

    factor =  (int(max(lon)) - int(min(lon)))+1
    unaLon = int(min(lon)-1)
    todasLon = []
    step = 0.25
    #r = 1/step
    rang = int((1/step)*factor)+1
    for i in range(rang): #multiplicar en funcion de cual es el step
        todasLon.append(unaLon)
        unaLon = unaLon + step
    #print todasLon


    aux = []
    paresOrdenados = []

    #paresOrdenados = zip(todasLat,todasLon)
    for i in range(len(todasLon)):
        for j in range(len(todasLat)):
            aux.append(todasLat[j])
            aux.append(todasLon[i])
            paresOrdenados.append(aux)
            aux = []
    #print (paresOrdenados)

    from math import floor

    def find_cell(coord):
        return [floor(coord[0]*2)/2, floor(coord[1]*2)/2]

    vectorVectores = []
    aux = []
    for j in range(len(paresOrdenados)):
        if len(aux) != 0:
            vectorVectores.append(aux)
            aux = []
        for i in range(len(coordenadas)):
            if find_cell(coordenadas[i]) == paresOrdenados[j]:
                aux.append(coordenadas[i])

    auxlat = []
    auxlon = []
    latsProm = []
    lonProm = []
    for j in range(len(vectorVectores)):
        vec = vectorVectores[j]
        for i in range(len(vec)):
            auxlat.append(vec[i][0])
            auxlon.append(vec[i][1])
        latsProm.append(np.average(auxlat))
        lonProm.append(np.average(auxlon))
        auxlat = []
        auxlon = []

    coords = zip(latsProm, lonProm)
    print coords

    print "cantidad de coordenadas originales: ", len(coordenadas)
    print "Cantidad de coordenadas después de promediar: ",         len(vectorVectores)
```